# All-in-one app for communicators and JIRA

Tags: software-recommendation, skype, google-hangouts, slack

is some application which would use one interface for all communicators (Skype, Slack, Teams, Hangouts), and transfer only data through some API?

I believe this is how exactly works these communicators as app installed. And I believe, functions/structure are same for all these apps (users, groups, messages, send file, receive file, etc.), but just data transfer is through another protocol, and "services for data transfer" have just different names.

Videocall and call is not needed, but it would be perfect if there will be this function too.

And reason? Now I am using four communicators, so this is really drastic, for my CPU and RAM too, so just one native app with same simple look (I don't need some graphical faetures which are staring HW resources), which will transfer ONLY data would be perfect!

NO web interface substituters, which are presented as "applications" for all you communicators, but it is only another truncated web browser, for example Rambox, etc. Better is classic web browser then.

And second question, is some JIRA Atlassian native app for Ubuntu? Because through web interface is this "app" really sloooooooooow, because it takes a lot of CPU and RAM.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I mean maybe something similar like Evolution for emails.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @K7AAY It could be, but I am searching especially for linux.

Comment: You can specify Ubuntu there....

Comment: @K7AAY Done. Do you know how data transfer works? Some API? Thanks.

Comment: Regret not; suggest another question, and please state the use case whcn asking, as some folks really want to know before answering.